# Wordpress Easy Contact Forms integration via php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form

I am trying to get Wordpress Easy Contact Forms plugin to my page by adding it to a page via text editor by using following: `[easy_contact_forms fid=1]` and then echoing the page content with php:

```
<?php 
$post51 = get_post( 51);
echo $post51->post_content; 
?>
```

However it just prints `[easy_contact_forms fid=1]` instead of actual form.

How do I get the form via php instead of the text content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because $post51->post_content hasn't had the shortcodes "executed".

try:

```
$post51 = get_post( 51 );
echo do_shortcode($post51->post_content);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode